# Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, broadcasting

I get some infomation that Android devices can now function in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) peripheral mode. Apps can use this capability to broadcast their presence to nearby devices from New in Android L.I'm making an application about this.

I was all configured(i.e. Settings for Bluetooth LE advertising and Advertisement data to be advertised in advertisement packet),When I started to startAdvertising,I found that I cannot listen to incoming connections.Who can help me?

I am a based on l-developer-preview-reference API(Added Package : android.bluetooth.le) to develop.

Comment: the L developer preview is, by definition a developer preview, and as such doesn't contain all the functionality the final build will have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I seem to find the way, but need to verify

Comment: When downloading the Android L (API 20, L Preview) using the SDK manager I'm still not getting the android.bluetooth.le namespace in my IDE. How did you add the android.bluetooth.le package?

Comment: hi,you should create new Android virtual device that target build Android L(perview),and you can create your Android application that build target android l.

Answer (score 4):

Any device with Android 4.3+ and a Bluetooth Low Energy chipset can detect beacons with this library. As of December 2014, this is approximately 40 percent of Android devices according to the [Google Play Store](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) and growing quickly.

To transmit as Peripheral Mode, Android 5.0+ and firmware supporting Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode are required. As of December 2014, only Nexus 6 and Nexus 9 devices are known to have firmware that supports Bluetooth Low Energy Peripheral Mode.